# How to remove top/bottom padding of math in MathJax?

Tags: html, css, mathjax

How do I set the top and botton padding in `div` and `ul` elements to 0?

Here's a screenshot of the effect I would like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    prefer: {
    Chrome: "CommonHTML"
    },
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],

    tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    "HTML-CSS": { color: "red"}
    },
    displayAlign: "left"
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js? 
config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid">
        \[My custom text\]
    </div>

    <ul style="border: 1px solid">
        <li style="border: 1px solid blue">\[x^2+x^4-x^5\]</li>
        <li style="border: 1px solid red">\[y^2+y^4-y^5\]</li>
    </ul>    
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be due to the preview element adding unexpected vertical space. This might be considered a bug in MathJax so I've filed https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few css (with the appropriate selectors) can solve the problem:

- hide empty elements
- reset margins

```css
li *:empty{
  display: none;
}


.mjx-chtml.MJXc-display{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    prefer: {
    Chrome: "CommonHTML"
    },
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],

    tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    "HTML-CSS": { color: "red"}
    },
    displayAlign: "left"
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid">
        \[My custom text\]
    </div>

    <ul style="border: 1px solid">
        <li style="border: 1px solid blue">\[x^2+x^4-x^5\]</li>
        <li style="border: 1px solid red">\[y^2+y^4-y^5\]</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: How did you know that will use css element name "mjx-chtml.MJXc-display" ?

Comment: I don't really know, but inspecting the element (right click on it) or the generated DOM (by hiting F12, in most browsers), you can see (margins and paddings graphically represented) which elements you have to select and chose the right selectors. The more selective, the better. For example, in your specific case, you can refine : `ul#my_ul_id li .mjx-chtml.MJXc-display`. Also be aware that it works with your specified config but you may have to add others selectors with others config and test behaviors between different  platforms